# parameter passing from CDE to PDI pentaho

Tags: parameter-passing, pentaho, pdi

I have a scenario to pass parameters from pentaho cde using kettle to pentaho data integration and then update the table using the passed parameter in PDI. How can i pass the parameter and get the passed parameter in PDI?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Pentaho plugin builder, SPARKL.

With it you can upload a transformation as a callable endpoint and use a CDE dashboard to call it.

First of all, you need a transformation that expects parameters. You can try it with a test one before going to a more advanced transformation:

> Example:
>   [image: parameters]

*defining a parameter and fetching with a Get Variables step*

---

Second you will create a new plugin on SPARKL.

> Sparkl welcome screen
>   [image: sparkl]

Give your plugin a name and add a kettle endpoint to it. If you now look at your pentaho-solutions/system folder, you will have a new folder with the plugin name. Open it and find the ktr file inside the subfolders to replace it with your transformation.

---

The last step is to add a new dashboard to your plugin and edit it. If you go to the datasources tab now, notice the datasources with 'endpoint' in the name. We will access them by code, but is good to know they are here so you can read data from it too, not just input data.

add a new resource of javascript to your CDE layout with the following code:

```
var myPluginName = {};
(function(myself) {
  myself.runEndpoint = function (pluginId, endpoint, opts) {

    if (!pluginId && !endpoint) {
      Dashboards.log('PluginId or endpointName not defined.');
      return false
    }

    var _opts = {
      success: function () {
        Dashboards.log(pluginId + ': ' + endpoint + ' ran successfully.')
      },
      error: function (){
        Dashboards.log(pluginId + ': error running ' + endpoint + '.')
      },
      params: {},
      systemParams: {},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
    var opts = $.extend( {}, _opts, opts);
    var url = Dashboards.getWebAppPath() + '/plugin/' + pluginId + '/api/' + endpoint;
    function successHandler (json) {
      if (json && json.result == false) {
        opts.error.apply(this, arguments);
      } else {
        opts.success.apply( this, arguments );
      }
    }
    function errorHandler () {
      opts.error.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    if (endpoint != 'renderer/refresh' ) {
      var ajaxOpts = {
        url: url,
        async: true,
        type: opts.type,
        dataType: opts.dataType,
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        data: {}
      }
    } else {
      var ajaxOpts = {
        url: url,
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: opts.dataType,
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        data: {}
      }
    }
    _.each( opts.params , function ( value , key) {
      ajaxOpts.data['param' + key] = value;
    });

    _.each(opts.systemParams , function (value , key) {
      ajaxOpts.data[key] = value;
    });
    $.ajax(ajaxOpts)
  }
})(myPluginName);
```

You can change myPluginName with whatever you want but that enables you to call that endpoint sending parameters with any button. To do so you can use that code:

```
myPluginName.runEndpoint(
                    'myPluginName', // Plugin identifier.
                    'endpointName', // Put your endpoint name here!
                    {
                      params: {
                      'EXAMPLE_PARAMETER' : foo_bar
                      },
                      success: function() { Dashboards.fireChange('refresh', 1); alert('data sent'); },
                      error: function() { alert('Ops, something went wrong. Check the logs.'); }
                    })
```

You can keep track of the execution by monitoring the bi-server logs.

More information on the sources:

[Diethard Steiner - Blog](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/sparkl-create-your-own-app-for-pentaho.html)
[Francesco Corti - Blog](http://fcorti.com/pentaho-sparkl/how-to-interact-with-endpoints-pdi-jobs-or-transformations/)
*Follow these guys, they are amazing.*

Comment: You don't need sparkl. A plain Kettle CDA datasource is enough. You just need to make sure that you set not only the query parameters, but also the mapping between CDA parameters and kettle parameters, by filling up the Variables tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, or you could just create a CDA data source, which takes a parameter as defined in your transformation.

Params are passed to CDA via the usual &paramYOURPARAMNAME=x syntax on the URL.

In the transformation you get the parameter using the get variables step.

Did I miss something?